# Is this SDP analytically solvable?

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker, semidefinite-programming

I am studying the following semi-definite problem:

$$\begin{array}{rl} \textrm{Given:} & W \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \\
\textrm{Minimize:} & u_1 + u_2 + \ldots + u_n \\
\textrm{Subject to:} & \forall i \in [n]:\\
& \begin{bmatrix} X & e_i \\ e_i^\intercal & u_i \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \\
& (W^\intercal X W)_{ii} \leq 1
\end{array}$$

where $e_i$ is the $n$-dimensional column vector with 1 in the $i$-th position and 0 elsewhere.

As part of trying to understand it, I have been looking at the case where $W = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Setting $X = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & c\end{bmatrix}$ turns the SDP into:

$$\begin{array}{rl} \textrm{Minimize:} & u_1 + u_2 \\
\textrm{Subject to:} \\
& \begin{bmatrix} a & b & 1 \\ b & c & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & u_1 \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \\
& \begin{bmatrix} a & b & 0 \\ b & c & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & u_2 \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \\
& a + 2b + c \leq 1 \\
& a \leq 1 \end{array}$$

Looking at the principal minors of the two matrices gives the following constraints (after removing several redundancies):

$$\begin{eqnarray} a, c, u_1, u_2 & \geq & 0 \\
ac - b^2 & \geq & 0 \\
a u_1 & \geq & 1 \\
c u_2 & \geq & 1 \\
(ac - b^2) u_1 & \geq & c \\
(ac - b^2) u_2 & \geq & a \\
 \end{eqnarray}$$

I have tried to find the optimum via the KKT conditions, by constructing the Lagrangian:

$$\begin{eqnarray} \mathcal{L}(a, b, c, u_1, u_2; \lambda) & = & u_1 + u_2 - \lambda^\intercal \begin{bmatrix} a \\ c \\ u_1 \\ u_2 \\ ac - b^2 \\ 1 - a u_1 \\ 1 - c u_2 \\ (ac - b^2)u_1 - c \\ (ac - b^2)u_2 - a \\ 1 - a \\ 1 - (a + 2b + c) \end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}$$

and setting the derivatives to zero, but I couldn't see an obvious solution.

So, is there a way to analytically find the optimum? Is there a simplification or modification or duality trick that I've missed?

Comment: Is $X$ always invertible?

Comment: Also, is $X$ always given or is it a decision variable (i.e. it is unknown and needs to be determined)?

Comment: $X$ is an $n \times n$ decision variable matrix. It is symmetric, but I'm not sure that it can be assumed to be invertible (note that from the semi-definite constraints its determinant is non-negative but not necessarily strictly positive).

Comment: The constraint $$ c u_2 \ge1 $$ was missed. Without this, you can set all variables to zero to get zero optimal value.

Comment: @Amir I also dropped the constraint $au_1 \geq 1$ because the combination of $ac - b^2 \geq 0$ and $(ac - b^2)u_1 \geq c$ (and its cousin) provides a stronger constraint.

Comment: They cannot be dropped. By the current constraints, the optimal solution is zero.

Comment: Ah, I see you're right. It would be a little different if they were strict inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

First, the $n$ constraints
$$
\begin{bmatrix} X & e_i \\ e_i^\intercal & u_i \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0
$$
can each be equivalently replaced by the following three constraints due to the [generalized Schur complement lemma](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2021/05/19/schur-complement.html#characterizing-symmetric-positive-semidefinite-matrices) (see also [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2099662) in case this link breaks)
$$
\begin{align}
X &\succeq 0 \tag{1} \\
(I - XX^\dagger)e_i &= 0 \tag{2} \\
u_i - e_i^T X^\dagger e_i &\geq 0 \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
where $X^\dagger$ is the pseudo-inverse of $X$. Next, the $n$ constraints $(I - XX^\dagger)e_1 = 0, \dots, (I - XX^\dagger)e_n = 0$ can be combined together to form the equivalent constraint $(I - XX^\dagger)I = 0$, or $XX^\dagger = I$. Because $X^\dagger$ always exists and is unique for every $X$, then the equaton $XX^\dagger = I$ implies that $X^\dagger$ is the right-inverse of $X$. However, because $X$ is square, then $X^\dagger$ is necessarily the left-inverse (and therefore the inverse) of $X$. This implies that $X$ is invertible. Moreover, because $X$ is positive semi-definite and invertible, then it is necessarily positive-definite. This implication also goes in the opposite direction, so we can replace constraints $(1), (2),$ and $(3)$ with the following equivalent constraints
$$
\begin{align}
X &\succ 0 \tag{4} \\
u_i &\geq e_i^T X^{-1} e_i \tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
We now turn our attention to the $n$ constraints $(W^\intercal X W)_{11} \leq 1, \dots, (W^\intercal X W)_{nn} \leq 1$. Each of these constraints can also be written as $e_i^TW^TXWe_i \leq 1$. At this point, we can proceed by choosing $X \succ 0$ such that $e_i^TW^TXWe_i \leq 1$ for each $i$. Then, by constraint $(5)$ above, the minimum value of $u_i$ is $e_i^T X^{-1} e_i$, such that the minimum value of your problem becomes $\sum_{i=1}^n e_i^T X^{-1} e_i$. Unfortunately, I'm not sure of any way to simplify the problem further without additional constraints.

---

If we add the constraint that $X = \varepsilon I$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$ (since $X \succ 0$), then the problem can be simplified further.

In this case, the constraint $e_i^TW^TXWe_i \leq 1$ becomes $\varepsilon \cdot e_i^TW^TWe_i \leq 1$. Therefore, fix any $W$. Next, let $c = \max\{e_i^TW^TWe_i \mid i \in \{1,\dots,n\}\}$. If $c = 0$, then choose any $\varepsilon > 0$. Otherwise, choose any $\varepsilon$ such that $0 < \varepsilon \leq \frac{1}{c}$. This choice ensures that the $n$ constraints $(W^\intercal X W)_{11} \leq 1, \dots, (W^\intercal X W)_{nn} \leq 1$ are satisfied for $X = \varepsilon I$.

Finally, we are left with the $n$ constraints $u_1 \geq e_1^T X^{-1} e_1, \dots, u_n \geq e_n^T X^{-1} e_n$ given in $(5)$. Because $X = \varepsilon I$, then $X^{-1} = \frac{1}{\varepsilon}I$, such that each of these constraints becomes $u_i \geq \frac{1}{\varepsilon} e_i^T e_i$. Because $e_i^T e_i = 1$ for each $i$, then each constraint becomes $u_i \geq \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$.

Therefore, to solve your problem, we choose $u_i = \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ for each $i$, such that the minimum value is $\sum_{i=1}^n u_i = \frac{n}{\varepsilon}$. Because this minimum value depends on $\varepsilon$, and because we have some control over the choice of $\varepsilon$, then we can improve the strategy for choosing $\varepsilon$ mentioned above. More specifically, if $c = 0$, then let $\varepsilon = \infty$. Otherwise, let $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{c}$, such that $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ is minimized.

Because the choice of $\varepsilon$ depends on $W$, then the choice of each $u_i$, and the minimal value of your problem, will also depend on $W$.

Comment: This is some really great insight on the original SDP, but doesn't really answer my question about trying to analytically solve the specific 2x2 case. Your last part is interesting, but unfortunately the context of the problem means that we're actually hoping to get solutions where $X$ is highly non-diagonal.

Comment: @ConMan my apologies. I thought that you were looking for a closed-form solution for the general case and not the $2 \times 2$ case. Would it be OK to leave this answer in case it is useful for future readers? I’ll also try to edit it for the $2 \times 2$ case if I have the time…

Comment: I'm quite happy for you to leave this here. It's still useful information :)